# Как сделать чтобы сообщение в группе от бота видели только админы данной группы? aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Как сделать чтобы сообщение в группе от бота видели только админы данной группы? aiogram

Comment: А такое возможно реализовать в телеграмме?

Comment: Я думаю да, message_thread_id может как-то с этим